# SOLVED: Redux selector - calculating the difference between two selector returned values

Tags: javascript, react-redux

**SOLUTION at the bottom**

I have a dropdown menu and as I choose an element from it - it should no longer be available in the dropdown.

I fetch from the api available products, store them in redux - same with chosen products.

What I want to do is have an array of all the products(done), array of the chosen products(done), and array that is being displayed on the front end is the list of all the products, filtering out elements that are in both arrays.

If I do calculation in the component, it only works after remounting the component.

```
const productsAvailable = state => state.products.allProducts;
const productsChosen = state =>state.newproducts.allProducts;
```

the calculation I do is:

```
  const productsToChoseFrom =
    productsAvailable &&
    productsAvailable.filter(
      el =>
        productsChosen &&
        !productsChosen.map(product => product).includes(el)
    );
```

How would I do this calculation in a selector?

//the answer is - using a creteSelector from reselect

```
const productsToChoseFrom = createSelector(
  productsAvailable,
  productsChosen,
  (productsOff, productsRendere) =>
    productsOff &&
    productsOff.filter(el =>
      productsRendere
        ? !productsRendere.map(cycle => cycle.interval).includes(el)
        : productsOff
    )
);
```

what I was actually missing is the ternary, that's why it wouldn't update..

Comment: I can't picture how that would work in the UI. If you have a dropdown and the user selects an item, the item instantly disappears from the dropdown?!?

Comment: it is no longer available in the dropdown, but is displayed on the UI, yes. and if you delete the chosen item, it goes back to the dropdown. I believe that to be irrelevant to the question - the question is how to make a selector which selects two different items from the store, and returns the difference